# Talend: How to integrate multiple files in folder?

Tags: csv, talend

I'm a beginner with Talend.

I would like to integrate 4 files.

For example,
In my folder, there are files like

```
aaa_yyyymmdd_1.csv , aaa_yyyymmdd_2.csv , aaa_yyyymmdd_3.csv  , aaa_yyyymmdd_4.csv

aba_yyyymmdd_1.csv , aba_yyyymmdd_2.csv , aba_yyyymmdd_3.csv , aba_yyyymmdd_4.csv
```

... (front part of the filename is dynamic with the date)

And these files have the same schema like
ID; Name; Location; Data(float);

I would like to integrate samename_samedate_1 , _2, _3, _4 files and make it like

```
ID; Name; Location; Data1; Data2; Data3; Data4;
```

Can you tell me how to design the job for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it.
Use a tFileList with a regular expression to get only the files whose name ends with a number. If you only have files like this in the directory, you can use a regular mask to get all of them ("*").
[image]

Since the files have the same schema, the tFileInputDelimited can read them one by one by using the global variable `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH"))`
The main logic is inside the tMap:
[image]

Depending on the file number, it decides on what goes in Data1, Data2, Data3, Data4 fields.
The current file name is retrieved using the variable `((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILE"))` and then we get the file number with this code `StringHandling.LEFT(StringHandling.RIGHT(Var.FileName, 5), 1)`